# How to listen in Android when the browser or some app started downloading a files?

Tags: android, android-intent, listener, android-download-manager

I need an application which will listen when some application starts downloading files (it will be evaluated like malicious behavior).

I was trying to do this with BroadcastReceiver and Intents, when I was filtering the "`android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE`" (in xml) and show it into `Toast`, when some item was downloaded to the device, but it was not working for me.

I found now that there is exist a `DownloadListener`, which contains a `onDownloadStart(..)` method.

Do you think, that this can solve my problem?

Comment: It would be useful if you could show some code in your question for what "is not working"

Answer (score 1):

Short of a custom version of the OS, you can't.  At best, you could get a subset of requests that use DownloadManager.  But most downloads don't use that-  they just make direct HTTP requests. There's no way to track those from another application.  If you were to use a custom version of the OS you could, but to get everything you'd pretty much need to be built into the Linux networking subsystem.